# Marking pivot points that are related to previous pivot points

Tags: pine-script

In reading some blog I found the following definition of pivot points.

> A pivot high is a candle that has a higher high than the candle that
>   came before it and the candle that comes after it. Second-order pivot
>   highs are first-order pivot highs that are preceded and followed by
>   lower first-order pivot highs. By preceded here it means that the
>   next/previous pivot high has this property of being lower.

Now I'd like to write a pine script that would be able to mark such second order pivot highs and perhaps even higher (third, fourth order pivot highs)

I am having a bit of trouble thinking how to set up such program since I don't understand how to access context in Pine. Ie. given that the current candle is a pivot high, how can I assess where the previous and next pivot highs are and what their respective high/low values are?

Can suggest an example or perhaps a solution for this problem?

Comment: A similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54190749/problem-with-pine-scripts-plotshapes-offset).

Answer (score 1):

In pine you can't look into "future", e.g. values of next bars. However, theoretically we may draw pivot *after* his range, but pine allow draw only on *current* bar. But pine v4 [is coming](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12ogvjzasBJSXerSOql4b9KwkE3wUlsc5HgA5qGhoYXk/edit#heading=h.ck6i1rzvv0a), which allow drawing on any bar, not only current

Answer (score 0):

How @kuznet1 correctly mentioned, you cannot look into the future (at the values of the coming bars),but it's possible to look at the past bars. You can implement it like that:

```
prevHigh = high[1]
```

So the tradingview's pivot point is calculated like that: `(high[1] + low[1] + close[1])/3` (actually previous *dayly* high, low and close are used for the calculation in intraday).

Maybe there's a way to calculate pivot point additionally using next bar, but IMHO it's a wrong way to calculate, because in realtime you don't have the ability peeping into tomorrow's trades.